# Dynamic routing using graphQL in a Next.js app

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo

I'm building a webpage that consumes the spaceX graphQL api, using apollo as a client. On the landing page I want to display a 'launches' card, that when clicked on, directs to a new page with details about that particular launch, as below:

**index.js**

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client"
import Link from 'next/link'

export const getStaticProps = async () => {

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql/',
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query GetLaunches {
        launchesPast(limit: 10) {
          id
          mission_name
          launch_date_local
          launch_site {
            site_name_long
          }
          links {
            article_link
            video_link
            mission_patch
          }
          rocket {
            rocket_name
          }
        }
      }
    `
  });

  return {
    props: {
      launches: data.launchesPast
    }
  }
}

export default function Home({ launches }) {

  return (
    <div>
      {launches.map(launch => {
        return(
          <Link href = {`/items/${launch.id}`} key = {launch.id}>
            <a>
              <p>{launch.mission_name}</p>
            </a>
          </Link>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've set up a new page `items/[id].js` to display information about individual launches, but this is where the confusion is. Using a standard REST api I'd simply use `fetch`, then append the id to the end of the url to retrieve the desired data. However I'm not sure how to do the equivalent in graphQL, using the `getStaticPaths` function. Any suggestions?

Here's `items/[id]/js`, where I'm trying to render the individual launch data:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client"

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://api.spacex.land/graphql/",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query GetLaunches {
        launchesPast(limit: 10) {
          id
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  const paths = data.map((launch) => {
    return {
      params: { id: launch.id.toString() },
    };
  });

  return {
      paths,
      fallback:false
  }

};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const id = context.params.id
// not sure what to do here
}

const Items = () => {
    return ( 
        <div>
            this is items
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Items;
```

Comment: @John have you figure out the solution ? i am facing the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

for getStaticPaths

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: launchesPastQuery, // this will query the id only
  });
  return {     
    paths: data.CHANGE_THIS.map((param) => ({
      params: { id: param.id },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

**CHANGE_THIS** is the Query Type that follows data in the JSON response.

for getStaticProps

```js
export const getStaticProps = async ({
  params,
}) => {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: GetLaunchPastByID ,
    variables: { LaunchID: params.id, idType: "UUID" }, // the idType is optional, and the LaunchID is what you'll use for querying by it*
  });

  return {
    props: {
      launchesPast: data.CHANGE_THIS,
    },
  };
```

The launchPastQueryByID is like:

```
const GetLaunchPastByID = gql`
  query LaunchPastByID($LaunchID: UUID!) { // UUID is id type
    CHANGE_THIS(id: $LaunchID) {
      id
      //...
    }
  }
`;
```

sorry for not giving you the correct queries, spacex.land is currently down.